# DataGrid DataBindings Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagrid

DataGrid DataBindings Error

```
class Test1
{
   public DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
   public BindingSource sr = new BindingSource();
}

class Test2
{

    Test1 ta =new Test1();

    DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
    table1.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
    table1.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
    table1.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
    table1.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    table1.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
    table1.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
    table1.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
    table1.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
    table1.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

    ta.table1 = table1 ;

   datagridview dgv = new datagridview();
   dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true ;
   dgv.DataBindings.Add("DataSource",ta,"table1");
}
```

the above code giving me "Cannot bind to the property or column table1 on the DataSource.Parameter name: dataMember." . What mistake i ma doing here ,i did not get it .Can any one help me ?

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DataSource` property directly to bind your data source like

```
dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgv.DataSource = ta.table1;
```

Well per your posted code the object data source you are passing is wrong, it has to be `ta.table1` instead of just `ta`

```
   dgv.DataBindings.Clear();
   dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
   dgv.DataBindings.Add("DataSource",ta.table1,"DataSource");
```

Also change the below line as

```
DataTable table1 = new DataTable("table1");
```

See MSDN documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6y3aby2(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples for more information

Comment: I am in the situation that using data binding to bind to the data source. Can you help me in finding the issue with databindings.add() method .

Comment: after changing like above , i am getting same error .Thank you for your response .

Comment: After adding name to the table also the same error occurring .DataTable table1 = new DataTable("table1");.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could always create an object list and bind the list.  Create a "Patient" class with the parameters you posted (Dosage, DrugName, PatientName, and Time).  Then create objects and add them to a list and finally set the DGV datasource equal to that list.  Here's some sample code that could help you:

```
DataGridView dgvPatient = new DataGridView();      //Create DGV
List<Patient> patientList = new List<Patient>();   //Create list
//Create and populate your object patient
Patient p1 = new Patient(###, "DrugName", "PatientName", DateTime);
patientList.Add(p1);                              //Add to list

dgvPatient.DataSource = typeof(Patient);
dgvPatient.DataSource = patientList;              //Assign to DGV
```

This is a different way to go about doing it but has worked pretty well for me in the past.  Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Yahtzee thank you for you reply.According to  you suggestion , the above suggestion is worked for me. But i need to bind the Data Source property of DataGridView using DataBindings.Add method ,this is not working for me .I d't know why it's not working,i am in need of help in that .